# Is this block-matrix multiplication idea correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to get better at factoring matrices into special forms, e.g. block upper/lower triangular, so I was wondering whether I have this correct.

If matrices A through H are square and of the same size, nxn, is my matrix on the RHS correct?  I basically treated the blocks as scalars, and performed the ordinary matrix multiplication techniques.

If it is correct, now what if A were mxn?  Does this just require a bit more, e.g., so long as E and F are **$nxm$**, for the matrix multiplication to make sense, then again I can treat the blocks as scalars and proceed with ordinary matrix multiplication?  (And if B were mxn, then G and H would need to be nxm, etc.)

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        A & B  \\
        C & D  \\
                \end{bmatrix}
* 
       \begin{bmatrix}
        E & F  \\
        G & H  \\
                \end{bmatrix}
 =  \begin{bmatrix}
        AE+BG & AF+BH  \\
        CE+DG & CF+DH  \\
                \end{bmatrix} $$

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you should really try to convince yourself that it works, even for rectangular blocks (of proper sizes, of course).

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for the quick response, @MartinArgerami.  Have a great day :-)